# flutter PropertyChangeNotifier ignore: mixin_inherits_from_not_object

Tags: flutter, dart

Working with flutter I'm struggling with notifying a model class parameters about changes coming from the Firestore DB.

I'm trying to use plugin [property_change_notifier](https://pub.dev/packages/property_change_notifier)
Using the example:

```
// ignore: mixin_inherits_from_not_object
class MyModel with PropertyChangeNotifier<String> {
  int _foo = 0;
  int _bar = 0;

  int get foo => _foo;
  int get bar => _bar;

  set foo(int value) {
    _foo = value;
    notifyListeners('foo');
  }

  set bar(int value) {
    _bar = value;
    notifyListeners('bar');
  }
}
```

I've added the ignore remark and even tried to set the `analysis_option.yaml` with this rule, but I still get the message:

```
The class 'PropertyChangeNotifier' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than Object.dart(mixin_inherits_from_not_object)
```

When I try to build the project it then shows the following error:

```
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/ngplayground/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType'.

      return nullCheck(context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(type) as PropertyChangeModel);
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\ngplayground\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this one as well

Answer (score 1):

you just need to change

```
class MyModel with PropertyChangeNotifier<String>
```

to

```
class MyModel extends PropertyChangeNotifier<String>
```

and it should work

Comment: Shouldn't that be `extends` instead of `extend`?

Comment: @fravolt yup You are right, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

This is the official solution the author introduced on the main page of PropertyChangeNotifier.

https://pub.dev/packages/property_change_notifier#mixin-compilation-error

It is recommended to add **// ignore: mixin_inherits_from_not_object** over your class.

[add ignore comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk5pR.jpg)

Or just extend your class with PropertyChangeNotifier.